# How to populate author, branch, commit, message in Cypres Dashboard in CI with Jenkins?

Tags: javascript, jenkins, github, continuous-integration, cypress

I'm trying to get the commit information details in the [Cypress Dashboard](https://www.cypress.io/dashboard/). I haven't been able to accomplish just yet, but I have made some advances though...

I'll describe what I have done so far:

- Installed the [commit-info](https://github.com/cypress-io/commit-info) npm package by running the command:

`npm install --save @cypress/commit-info`

- Import the plugin in `plugin/index.js` file like so:

```
const { commitInfo } = require('@cypress/commit-info');

module.exports = on => {
  on('file:preprocessor', file => {
    commitInfo().then(console.log);
  });
};
```

Now I get all the information, author, branch, commit & message, in the terminal!:)
However, I still don't have the information details linked to my Cypress Dashboard.

This is what I currently get:

[image]

What're the next steps? The documentation is not clear to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In our case we run everything inside a docker container.  We copy our code into the container but do not copy the .git directory, it's large, time consuming, and we don't need it.  `@cypress/commit-info` [assumes there is a .git directory](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Environment-variables), so since there isn't, it doesn't work.

We overcame this by setting [the values cypress expects](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Environment-variables) explicitly in the cypress run command in our `Jenkinsfile`:

```
def commitMessage = sh(script:"git log --format=%B -n 1 ${env.GIT_COMMIT}", returnStdout:true).trim()
def commitAuthor = sh(script:"git log --format='%an' -n 1 ${env.GIT_COMMIT}", returnStdout:true).trim()
def commitEmail = sh(script:"git log --format='%ae' -n 1 ${env.GIT_COMMIT}", returnStdout:true).trim()

def cypressVars = "COMMIT_INFO_BRANCH=${env.GIT_BRANCH} COMMIT_INFO_SHA=${env.GIT_COMMIT} COMMIT_INFO_REMOTE=${env.GIT_URL} COMMIT_INFO_MESSAGE=\"${commitMessage}\" COMMIT_INFO_AUTHOR=\"${commitAuthor}\" COMMIT_INFO_EMAIL=${commitEmail}"

// call cypress however you do and include cypressVars as part of the command
```

Comment: where should I add the code snippet that you provided me? Please don't assume I have any knowledge on these topics :) Btw, note that I got already all the info printed in my terminal. I just need to sync with the Dashboard

Comment: This goes in your Jenkinsfile, right before you call `cypress run`.  If you provide the code for how you're running Cypress in CI I can edit my answer to be more tailored to your situation.  This is all assuming it's the same issue - you running inside a docker container.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately, I  cannot share it. But at least you gave me some pointer!

Comment: thanks finally I understand more about the concept & used your code and worked like a charm!